# Android - reading/writing to online mysql database

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I've just written a short Android app which stores userdata in the phone-side sqlite database.

What I'd like to be able to do is to add this to an online database (I currently have a mysql database with my webhosts, but if there's any easier way then I'm open to suggestions), but it'll be subject to condition (Such as if a certain value doesn't already exist). I'd also like to be able to get data from this online database too to be added to the sqlite database on the phone.

I've had a look around and people seem to suggest using php as a go-between for that, but is that the easiest way? there aren't any mysql helper classes that could just interface directly or anything?

Newbie question I know, but the project was to teach myself how Android works so getting stuck in is the way to go..

Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes; using PHP is an example of an easier way to go. You need to create web services which allow you to interact between the android phone and a MySQL database.  To my knowledge you can't go directly to a database hook; as you need to have something that can hook in.  Also it would be a security issue if you put on each and all of your phones the connection information for your database.

Think if you had to change the host of your DB as your traffic grew large that you needed to upgrade; this would be a new update in the store and all clients would need to update this; otherwise you would be maintaining two code bases.

By using PHP you are able to create that middle level and easily interact with the DB.

Here is a quick article on creating REST PHP Web Service.  [Tutorial](http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/)

Good Luck!

Comment: Very nicely explained, re: the benefits of making php sit in the middle, thanks! does that make it any more difficult to read data? should it be displayed as HTML for the app to scan through (either data or errors for values already existing etc.?)

Comment: With PHP in the middle; you can format the content from the DB in any fashion you wish.  For passing it down to the phone; I normally like to pass it in a JSON format, as the JSON parsers on android are faster than the XML parsers.  With PHP You are handling a request and returning the data creating it into any form you wish.

Comment: you are a star, thanks very much for explaining that! I'll get started on that article you posted